# How to get rid of 0 in X-axis

Tags: r, highcharts

I am plotting a highchart. Cannot get rid of this 0 in X-Axis. Tried a lot of things. Please help.

```
hc1 <- highchart(type = "chart" ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = FALSE)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Confirmed", data = 
CDR_ordered$Confirmed_ordered.Confirmed) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Recovered", data = 
CDR_ordered$Recovered_ordered.Recovered, color = "#FFFF00") %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Deaths", data = CDR_ordered$Deaths_ordered.Deaths, color = "#FF0000") %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Cases", categories = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Affected"), minorTickInterval = "auto", minorGridLineDashStyle = "LongDashDotDot")

hc1 <- hc1 %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column",
           options3d = list(enabled = TRUE, beta = 10, alpha = 10)) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google()) %>%
  hc_credits(
    enabled = TRUE, text = "Source: JHU CSS",
    href = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv",
    style = list(fontSize = "10px"))
```

Please check the image below for better understanding

[image: Get Rid of 0 on X-Axis]

[image: This is my data]

[image: How do I get rid of this 0 now?]

Comment: Could you provide the list of all the packages you are using? I am not able to just copy/paste and run your code in R studio.

Comment: This is data from JHU CSS for Coronavirus. The package used is library(highcharter) for plotting highchart

Comment: How can I attach this data to the chart? Anyway, Ben's answer should be enough for you. You can just disable xAxis.labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:

You have two `hc_xAxis` - you can get rid of the first one.

You can add `labels = list(enabled = FALSE)` to `hc_Axis` to hide 0 label on the xAxis.

To remove the label on mouse hover, you can include `categories = " "`.

```
hc_xAxis(categories = " ", title = list(text = "Cases", categories = FALSE), labels = list(enabled = FALSE))
```

If this doesn't work, please use `dput(head(CDR_ordered))` (or something similar) and edit your question with the output. There are likely alternatives to display your results with highchart.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks so much, man. I was really struggling on this thing. Really Appreciate this.